# Cannot import MySQLdb in Python3, but Python2 works

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-python

I installed the module using `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`.

Now, it works for Python 2, but not for Python 3.

How may I get it working for Python 3?

```
ubuntu:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
ubuntu:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

ubuntu:~$ python -c 'import MySQLdb'
ubuntu:~$ python3 -c 'import MySQLdb'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the way you install packages, I assume you use a pre-18.04 ubuntu.

First, you should install `pip` for python 3. pip is the package manager that is being used for python. Use the following command `sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip`.
Then, use `pip3 install <package name>` to install your package

Bonus:
It is usually a good idea to install the following packages when developing python: `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install python3-mysqldb` worked for me. Apparently `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` only installed it for Python 2.